# How do I enable_logging for ModelMonitoringAlertConfig in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to `enable_logging` in `ModelMonitoringAlertConfig` I have tried:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as vertex_ai_beta
...
    alerting_config = vertex_ai_beta.ModelMonitoringAlertConfig(
    enable_logging=True,
    email_alert_config=vertex_ai_beta.ModelMonitoringAlertConfig.EmailAlertConfig(
        user_emails=NOTIFY_EMAILS
    )
)
```

gives:

```
 Unknown field for ModelMonitoringAlertConfig: enable_logging
```

but [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.ModelMonitoringAlertConfig) suggests it should work. What am I missing?

(I have also tried `aiplatform_v1beta1`.)

Answer (score 2):

`enable_logging` was added in 1.8.1 and i am using 1.7.0.